# Want to deploy my application on multi-node kafka cluster, but not able to connect docker conatainers internally

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  zookeeper-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  zookeeper-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 42181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  kafka-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
```

this is the example from confluence for multi-node cluster, used network mode=host. what address should i use for internal connection.

for example the below one is single-node kafka cluster

```
kafka:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

here I can use `kafka:29092` for internal connection.

i followed same approach for multi-node but getting error.
can anyone explain why this approach not work for multi-node cluster and how to establish internal connection.
thank you.

Comment: Running a Kafka cluster on one machine doesn't have many advantages and the network setup here won't work unless running it in Linux... Are you sure you want to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here I can use kafka:29092 for internal connection

That's because it was listed as an advertised listener for internal clients to connect to. `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092`

You've removed the service name from each of your brokers, so clients are now trying to connect to just the advertised `localhost` addresses and failing because the containers running your applications are therefore trying to connect to themselves (via localhost), not any of the kafka containers.

Comment: Please read this to understand the listeners in more detail https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Actually i tried with ```KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092``` option adding it to each service environment variable like ```KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:19092```  ```KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-2:29092``` and ```KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-3:39092``` but no luck

Comment: And what did you use in your application? `bootstrap.server` still set to just `kafka:29092`?

Comment: nope, i have used ```kafka-1:19092,kafka-2:29092,kafka-3:39092```

Comment: I would look at each kafka logs to make they are starting okay, then I'd look at the information stored in Zookeeper because that's how clients actually get the connection details for the cluster

Comment: ```kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:19093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:19092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"```

Comment: ```kafka-consumer_1_4d545fd3cdb4 | 2019-04-28 17:30:39 WARN  ClientUtils:76 - Couldn't resolve server kafka-1:19093 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka-1
kafka-consumer_1_4d545fd3cdb4 | 2019-04-28 17:30:39 WARN  ClientUtils:76 - Couldn't resolve server kafka-2:29093 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka-2
kafka-consumer_1_4d545fd3cdb4 | 2019-04-28 17:30:39 WARN  ClientUtils:76 - Couldn't resolve server kafka-3:39093 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka-3```

Comment: for single-node it works well, I don't what is the problem with multi-node

Comment: one more thing, when we use network mode as  ```host```, traffic is directly connecting with ethernet interface without virtual network right? if yes then why do we need to use ```KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS``` this. in that case for Interal and external both should be ```localhost``` right? I'm not sure about this, please help me out

Comment: Just because you use host network mode doesn't magically bypass the Kafka protocol handshakes. The DNS resolution is failing because your consumer isn't running within the Docker network and it's (correctly) receiving the advertised addresses (as explained by the blog post in my first comment). The short answer is that how your configure the addresses depends on which network you are running your clients from, but if you only use localhost addresses, then replication will not work, so you'd need 3 listeners for Docker network clients, host clients, and replication

Comment: Thank you! it makes sense. could you please suggest some links or any example's to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't have any. As mentioned earlier, running a cluster on one machine isn't useful. At least, not using Docker. It makes more sense with VMs if you are testing persistence and replication